# How to search JSON string for fields?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON string: `[{"number":"123-456-789","array":["1", "2"]}]`. I want check to see if this JSON contains a `"number"` field. What I am trying:

```
string jsonString = [{"number":"123-456-789","array":["1", "2"]}];
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray jsonObject = JArray.Parse(jsonString);
```

How do I then "search" this `jsonObject` for a specified field?

Comment: once it's decoded, then it's some kind of native object, not a string. you'd use the same iteration methods for that object as you would any other.

Comment: @MarcB Can you give an example, please?

Comment: `Feel free to recommend a method that does not rely on the "Newtonsoft" library :)` Oh god, why? That's often considered THE best JSON library for .NET out there.

Comment: @mason Very well. I shall edit the post :)

Comment: Are you able to represent the JSON with a .NET POCO and use JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize() ? [see link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) Then it's a matter of inspecting the POCO.

Comment: uhh... This doesn't compile.  You can't assign raw JSON to a string without making it a single string.  Did you forget to wrap it in quotes?

Comment: Why don't use isNaN function on the desired field after convert with JSON.parse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you would like to test if the "number" property exists, then you can use:

```
bool exists = jsonObject[0].Children<JProperty>().Any(p => p.Name == "number");
```

If you want to get the value of the "number" property, then you can use

```
string number = jsonObject[0]["number"].Value<string>();
```

**Edit**
Here is how to get the "array" property

```
string[] arr = jsonObject[0]["array"].Values<string>().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
        var isThereNumber = jsonObject[0]["number"];
        var isThereNumber2 = jsonObject[0]["number2"];
```

Cheers