# Loading in JSON as a resource to an object

Tags: c#

I have a large JSON file that I want to load into my project. I want to then search for the name and return the type. Example below:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Name1",
    "Type": "TypeA"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Name2",
    "Type": "TypeB"
  }
]
```

My problem is that I'm not sure what is the best way to do it. Should i be creating an object class and then loading the file into it?

I've been trying to do this by loading it from my resources. I just cant seem to do it, or find any example of others doing this which leads me to believe I'm doing it the wrong way. I've tried as below:

```
var resourceName = FS.Properties.Resources.types;
dynamic jsonDe = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TypeList>(resourceName);
```

And

```
dynamic jsonDe = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TypeList>("FS.Resources.types.json");
```

Any advice would be very welcome. Thanks

Comment: If i get your question correctly, you should be able to do `paste json as class` under space special in the edit menu.

Comment: Take a look at this question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496816/how-to-search-json-string-for-fields

Comment: I want to load from a file not a string

Comment: [Deserialize JSON from a file](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeWithJsonSerializerFromFile.htm)

Comment: I want to load from a resource not from filepath

Comment: read file as string and then parse it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the cleanest and most understandable solution possible:

```
public class Program
{
  public class MappedObject
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
  }

  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    // search query
    string searchFor = "Name1";
    // our json
    string jsonData = "[{\"Name\": \"Name1\",\"Type\": \"TypeA\"},{\"Name\": \"Name2\",\"Type\": \"TypeB\"}]";
    // I'm mapping the json string into a list of MappedObject (s)
    List<MappedObject> mappedObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MappedObject>>(jsonData);

    // I'm looping through this list to find the MappedObject
    // that matches the searchFor search query string
    foreach (MappedObject obj in mappedObjects)
    {
      if (obj.Name == searchFor)
      {
        // when I find it, I'll print the Type property
        Console.WriteLine(obj.Type);
      }
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
  }
}
```

If you want to read the json from an external resource, like a `.json` file you could do this:

```
public class Program
{
  public class MappedObject
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
  }

  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    // search query
    string searchFor = "Name1";

    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("file.json"))
    {
      // our json read from file.json
      string jsonData = r.ReadToEnd();
      // I'm mapping the json string into a list of MappedObject (s)
      List<MappedObject> mappedObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MappedObject>>(jsonData);

      // I'm looping through this list to find the MappedObject
      // that matches the searchFor search query string
      foreach (MappedObject obj in mappedObjects)
      {
        if (obj.Name == searchFor)
        {
          // when I find it, I'll print the Type property
          Console.WriteLine(obj.Type);
        }
      }
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is really helpful

Answer (score 4):

From here: [How to read embedded resource text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file)

You can use the [Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Reflection_Assembly_GetManifestResourceStream_System_String_) Method:

**Add the following usings**
    using System.IO;
    using System.Reflection;

**Set property of relevant file:**
Parameter `Build Action` with value `Embedded Resource`

**Use the following code**

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var resourceName = "MyCompany.MyProduct.MyFile.txt";

using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

`resourceName` is the name of one of the resources embedded in `assembly`. For example, if you embed a text file named `"MyFile.txt"` that is placed in the root of a project with default namespace `"MyCompany.MyProduct"`, then resourceName is `"MyCompany.MyProduct.MyFile.txt".` You can get a list of all resources in an assembly using the Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames Method.

A no brainer astute to get the resourceName from the file name only (by pass the namespace stuff):

```
string resourceName = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()
  .Single(str => str.EndsWith("YourFileName.txt"));
```

After that you can make use of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496816/how-to-search-json-string-for-fields) or [this](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeWithJsonSerializerFromFile.htm) **(suggested by users previously)** to Deserialize your values.

Answer (score 3):

A way to do this is to deserialize the Json file and store it in a data-class.
When the Json file is converted to a list of data-class objects that holds the information, it is possible to use Linq to search for a given value of a property.

See the following link for deserializing a JSON file [Deserialize Json From File.](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeWithJsonSerializerFromFile.htm)

The Linq query would look something like beneath.

```
arrayList.where(w => w.propertyName == "value of string").select(s => s.propertyName).
```

It is possible to retrieve a list of matching properties using the `.ToList()` or if you want a single property `.First()`.

Note that the `.First()` throws an exception when no matching values could be found. It's possible to use `.FirstOrDefault()`, this returns a null value there were no matching values.

When using the `.FirstOrDefault()` method you can add a null check displaying a message if the value you were looking for was found.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring a class to mimic your JSON structure is an option:

```
sealed class MyType
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Then you will be able to deserialize it in a typed list and filter according to a given name

```
private static string FindType(string json, string name)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyType>>(json)
                      .SingleOrDefault(nt => nt.Name == name)?
                      .Type ?? "No type found";
}
```

Note that this method assess that no record with the given name can be found, in which case it returns a default string.

If you want to use this method with a resource file:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(FindType(FS.Properties.Resources.types, "Name1")); //prints "Type1
    Console.WriteLine(FindType(FS.Properties.Resources.types, "name1")); //prints "No type found
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```